# Class not Found for apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI (3.17) to create some sheets with chart's.

I'm facing the follow problem when i use:

```
XSSFChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
bottomAxis.getMajorGridLines(); // here give error
```

it throw:

```
The type org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTChartLines cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

The method getMajorGridLines() from the type XSSFChartAxis refers to the missing type CTChartLines

The method addNewMajorGridlines() from the type CTValAx refers to the missing type CTChartLines
```

my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>
```

I found this class on ooxml-schemas 1.3, but now we are working with poi-ooxml-schemas 3.17.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you [read the Apache POI FAQ entry for this problem and follow the advice given there](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025)?

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks for reply, the way that I was searching i could not find this link. I add the dependency and no more erros.
  `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>`

Answer (score 3):

@Gagravarr thanks for reply, the way that I was searching i could not find this link. I add the dependency and no more erros.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```